# Any ideas, how to rectify this UV layout?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

I have this UV layout. Is there a smart way to straighten it? (I mean making it rectangular shape.)
For example something similar to lattice modifier, but in UV space.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just did a quick test, you could rotate / scale / move outer vertices to align them to a general square shape, then pin them into place with 'P' key, select all and run UV > Minimize Stretch... press Enter when you think it's fine... there are some manual tools also

[image]

Comment: very nice :) didn't know it could be done this efficiently

Comment: Wow! Cool solution! It helped me out a lot.
Thanks!